# Flash player memory usage - Flash builder profiler vs Activity monitor

Tags: flash, memory, monitoring, profiler, builder

Could somebody please explain me the relationship between the Current memory usage in Flash Builder /as can be seen in the profiler in the memory usage graph/ and the real memory usage /which can be seen for example in the activity monitor of OSX/. The thing is that the current memory in FB seems to report really small values, under 300K, however the activity monitor shows the real memory usage of Flash player debugger is growing and growing and growing. How is that possible? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory usage in the profiler is only the memory used by the objects allocated in the Flash virtual machine (AVM). In other words: Your main `Sprite` and any objects instantiated by your application, as well as behind-the-scene objects created by the AVM, such as the `Stage`.

Memory usage of the Flash player/debugger includes the process of the player/debugger and the AVM, which is just a native Mac/Windows application. The AVM executes your AS3 code somewhere inside of the Flash player, in its own isolated world.

If you want to keep an eye on your Flash application's memory usage, stick to the profiler.

Comment: Thanks for this info. So what you are saying is that it is normal that the flashplayerdebugger process takes 250+ megabytes even if the application hardly uses any?

Comment: That seems a little excessive, but yes, during profiling debugger memory keeps increasing (I just tested it myself). I assume because it's storing profiling data (method calls/timing, object allocation, etc.).